# laravel4 composer install got proc_open not available error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Now I am trying to use composer to install my php package but I got this error message:
$ composer install

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing filp/whoops (1.0.7)
    Downloading: 100%          

[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]                                   
The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.
```

edit :

after enable the proc_open function I got this error and also set my php memory_limit to 384M :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:990
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle(2, 'proc_open(): fo...', 'phar:///usr/loc...', 990, Array)
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(990): proc_open('stty -a | grep ...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array)
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(832): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getSttyColumns()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(797): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalDimensions()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(731): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->getTerminalWidth()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/com in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php on line 990
```

Comment: Having this problem in cPanel hosting where I have no hope of fixing it by activating that component.  Did you ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 24):

You should use php-cli to by-pass **disable_functions** temporarily.

```
php -d "disable_functions=" /path/to/composer install
```

Comment: To extend efesaid's answer, in composer.json I had to modify the php artisan optimize command so that it implemented disable_functions as well.

Comment: @iUseMagentoNow Could you elaborate your tip? After executing the installation as efesaid recommended I got a runtime exception from php artisan optimize. Where and/or how can I modify the command to run php with disabled functions temporarily as well?

Comment: Sure, I'll update this with the specifics when I'm able to, later. If you take a look at your Laravel composer.json there are a few artisan commands. Modify the optimize commands so that they contain `-d "disable_functions="`.

Answer (score 9):

Edit your `php.ini` file and search for the line

```
disable_functions = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait...
```

It should be disabled there and you must enabled it. This a security precaution.

Comment: "security prevention" - nice typo. You probably meant "security precaution". :) And if you are right, these functions are probably disabled for a reason, so think about enabling them.

Comment: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory. Instead of expanding my memory, are there any other solutions? thanks

Comment: If you are right, why does Laravel (and Homestead, as well) need those functions? Also, why are they all enabled by default on Windows, with WAMP, but not Linux?