# proc_open error when try to run artisan dump-autoload

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel, composer-php

When I try to run php artisan dump-autoload, I got this error:

```
 root@server:/var/mysite# php artisan dump-autoload
 Generating optimized class loader

   [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
   The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

 dump-autoload

 root@server:/var/mysite#
```

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 x64 on DigitalOcean.

any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the `proc_open` is disabled in your php.ini. Usually for security reason.

To be sure search the `disable_functions` directive in your php.ini and find out if `proc_open` is in that list. Or try with `function_exists('proc_open')`, this should return FALSE

Possible duplicate: [laravel4 composer install got proc_open not available error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911737/laravel4-composer-install-got-proc-open-not-available-error)

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 6 and higher (proc_open Error)**

It is because of Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode There is a workaround for this.

Publish flare config file `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

and in config/flare.php

update

```
'reporting' => [
        'anonymize_ips' => true,
        'collect_git_information' => false,
        'report_queries' => true,
        'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
        'report_query_bindings' => true,
        'report_view_data' => true,
    ],

'send_logs_as_events' => false,
```

Comment: I don't use Flare but get this error.