# I got an error to run cron at laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.3

I am using cpanel shared host and i use my cron job comment like

```
php /home/xxxxxx/public_html/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1

$schedule->command( 'inspire' )
             ->everyMinute()->appendOutputTo( storage_path( 'logs/update-active.log' ) );
```

It is triggering but i have some error log at laravel.log

```
[2016-09-04 05:51:01] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.' in /home/adminbot/public_html/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:144

#0 /home/adminbot/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.php(171): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->__construct(''/usr/bin/php' ...', '/home/adminbot/...', NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

How can i solve this ? please help me.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671920/proc-open-error-when-try-to-run-artisan-dump-autoload ...

Comment: make sure you post your updates

Comment: Ok i will post my update , i have already contact with my server admin to update that function.

[Here is my phpinfo file][1]
Do i need other function to enable?

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0W4hk.png

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue? I have also proc_open in disable_function row

Comment: This is an server issue, php server need to supprot proc_open , 
make sure your php support proc_open.